# Wordpress plugin interface not displaying properly

Tags: wordpress

I added a slider plugin. The interface is not appearing properly, the images, text etc seems to be overlapping. Not able to choose the desired settings.

For example, it appears like 
[image]

where as it should have been like [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database was not pointing to the correct URLs where the style files were located.

Right click -> Inspect element -> Console window showed "Failed to load resource - style.css".